# VisualVM: Is it possible to profile an application running on a remote server that only has JRE(no JDK)

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

I have two computers on a network(visible to each other) and I run JVisualVM on one of the computers. I wish to monitor a java application running on the other computer. Is it possible?

I tried adding a remote server and got the screen as below:

[image]

But after this what steps are to be followed to profile, lets say, com.myapp.MyApp running on the other computer?

P.S. The remote computer does not have a JDK installed(This is a constraint). It just has a JRE.

Comment: http://www.codefactorycr.com/java-visualvm-to-profile-a-remote-server.html

Comment: [Enno Shioji](http://stackoverflow.com/users/234901/enno-shioji), the solution given by you assumes that the remote system has a JDK installed. Is it possible to monitor the remote application if the system on which it is running does not have a JDK installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can VisualVM monitoring apps running on JRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681560/can-visualvm-monitoring-apps-running-on-jre)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do monitoring on remote host. JRE is enough! But it is not possible to do profiling on remote host as stated here:

https://visualvm.java.net/applications_remote.html

The number/deep of processes which are shown by VisualVM for profiling and Sampler (local or remote) are different. The prior one hat much more details!