# Can VisualVM monitoring apps running on JRE

Tags: java, performance, profiling, monitoring

as the headline mentioned: is it possible to connect VisualVM to an remote application running on JRE instead of JDK ? 
And yes, the VisualVM itself runs on JDK !

Kind regards
Dominik

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to try it? ;-)  Works fine locally, I thought it would but tried to be sure.  Have you tried and if so are you seeing errors?

Answer (score 0):

VisualVM connects to a running Java Virtual Machine (JVM).
And this JVM is contained both in the JDK and the JRE. 
In fact, the JDK is a JRE with additional tools and items to allow creating Java programs. If you only want to run them, you only need a JDK.

So yes, you can connect to a JRE-only install.

Comment: I have a low cost linux box where my application is running. It dont have a jdk but just a jre. Is there any tutorial where i can find how to use visualvm there? I am new to profiling :(